# Matching a column range based on a column label

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have written a spreadsheet for Excel 10 and am struggling with the last bit of formula.

I wrote this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(B7,'PO SHEET'!$K$7:$K$74))),('PO SHEET'!$W$7:$W$74))
```

However, column range W may vary between W and the text in row 6 of that column, which is the label for a particular worksheet.

Once this is done, it will feed information to my Summary sheet via this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B8,INDIRECT("'"&$F$6&"'!$J$2:$P$1000"),3,FALSE),0)
```

Comment: Sorry Column Range is W to AG

Comment: What is your problem don't you receive the expected result / error message? it's not clear from your question, please amend. Also please post some sample data to make your question more understandable.

Comment: the spreadsheet is build to manage a number of locations.

Comment: I have created a macro that will insert a new locations sheet when the "New ICON" is clicked. It then asks for the name of the new location which is inputted. The location name then will be in row 6 of columns W to AG dependent on its position. So where in the first formula is fixes the column a W, I need it to be variable and MATCH or INDEX the location name in row 6 of the relevant column. - Is that any clearer. Sorry new to this!!